# Restfull API multiple resources in unique call

Tags: php, json, api, rest, laravel

I'm building a restfull API for a forum and I have all controllers set up.

This is my setup

> www.project.com/api/v1/forum/categories -> returns all categories
>
> www.project.com/api/v1/forum/categories/{id}/discussions -> returns all discussions from 1 category

Now the point is that in the frond-end, my forum/categories page displays all categories, BUT, as most forums do I want to add data related to each category (number of discussions, last active discussion, etc)

My question is, what is better, add the specific data I need to the www.project.com/api/v1/forum/categories controller or should I call both resources (categories and discussions) and manipulate with the data I need my front-end.

I thought maybe making the api return more data than necesary could compensate the fact that I have to do more AJAX calls if I do it the proper way.

I hope i've expressed myself good enought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the better solution is making less requests, so you should try to get all relevant data using one request.

Of course it doesn't mean you should repeat your code for discussions - both in categories and discussions controller. Just create services that will reuse most of the code and launch it in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to have your /categories end point returning all the relevant data. This makes it a lot more reusable, because it means you won't have to recalculate the data every time you want to display it.

Comment: Yes I get it, but look how bad it scales.

First I have to gather all categories (1 call) 
Then once request is done I have to gather the discussions for each category (10 more calls)

Comment: I mean the summary data related to the discussions (number of discussions, last active discussion, etc) should also be part of /categories. That way, you only need to call /categories once.

Comment: Great, then we agree.

Thanks